# q interpreter not recalling history on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, kdb, q-lang

Last night I went to install q and kdb 32 bit on my system.  I have been using it at work and whenever I hit the up arrow key at work it recalls the previous command.  This does not seem to be working on my home install.  When I hit the up it it prints ^[[A.  How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I needed to install and run it with a program called rlwrap for command history.

`rlwrap q`

Comment: here it's written https://code.kx.com/q4m3/1_Q_Shock_and_Awe/#11-starting-q